# Add category banner to product view page

Tags: magento-1.9, product-view

Is there anyway I can add the category banner to the product view page. I tried adding the following code (taken from category/view.phtml) to product/view.phtml but it resulted in a 'fatal call error' can anyone help?

```
                        <?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>
        <?php
                $_helper    = $this->helper('catalog/output');
                $_category  = $this->getCurrentCategory();
                $_imgHtml   = '';
                if ($_imgUrl = $_category->getImageUrl()) {
                    $_imgHtml = '<p class="category-image"><img src="'.$_imgUrl.'" alt="'.$this->escapeHtml($_category->getName()).'" title="'.$this->escapeHtml($_category->getName()).'" /></p>';
                    $_imgHtml = $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_imgHtml, 'image');
                }
            ?>

            <?php if($_imgUrl): ?>
                <?php echo $_imgHtml ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var optionsPrice = new Product.OptionsPrice(<?php echo $this->getJsonConfig() ?>);
        </script>
        <div id="messages_product_view"><?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->toHtml() ?></div>
        <div class="product-view">
            <div class="product-essential">
                <form action="<?php echo $this->getSubmitUrl($_product, array('_secure' => $this->_isSecure())) ?>" method="post" id="product_addtocart_form"<?php if($_product->getOptions()): ?> enctype="multipart/form-data"<?php endif; ?>>
                    <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
                    <div class="no-display">
                        <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?php echo $_product->getId() ?>" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="related_product" id="related-products-field" value="" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="product-img-box">
                        <div class="product-name">
                            <h1><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></h1>
                        </div>
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('media') ?>
                    </div>

                    <div class="product-shop">
                        <div class="product-name">
                            <span class="h1"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></span>
                        </div>


                        <div class="extra-info">
                            <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'default', false)?>
                            <?php /* echo $this->getChildHtml('product_type_availability'); */ ?>
                        </div>

                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('alert_urls') ?>

                        <?php if ($_product->getShortDescription()):?>
                            <div class="short-description">
                                <div class="std"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, nl2br($_product->getShortDescription()), 'short_description') ?></div>
                            </div>
                        <?php endif;?>

                        <div class="price-info">
                            <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product); ?>
                            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('bundle_prices') ?>
                            <?php echo $this->getTierPriceHtml() ?>
                        </div>

                        <div class="add-to-cart-wrapper">
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_type_data') ?>
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('extrahint') ?>

                        <?php if (!$this->hasOptions()):?>
                            <div class="add-to-box">
                                <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addtocart') ?>
                                    <?php if( $this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow() || $_compareUrl=$this->helper('catalog/product_compare')->getAddUrl($_product)): ?>
                                        <span class="or"><?php echo $this->__('OR') ?></span>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                                <?php /* echo $this->getChildHtml('addto') ?>
                                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('sharing') */?>
                            </div>
                            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('extra_buttons') ?>
                        <?php elseif (!$_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                            <!--<div class="add-to-box">
                                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addto') ?>
                                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('sharing') ?>
                            </div>-->
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>

                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('other');?>

                        <?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $this->hasOptions()):?>
                            <?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container1', '', true, true) ?>
                        <?php endif;?>

                    </div>

                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('related_products') ?>

                    <div class="clearer"></div>
                    <?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $this->hasOptions()):?>
                        <?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container2', '', true, true) ?>
                    <?php endif;?>
                </form>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                //<![CDATA[
                    var productAddToCartForm = new VarienForm('product_addtocart_form');
                    productAddToCartForm.submit = function(button, url) {
                        if (this.validator.validate()) {
                            var form = this.form;
                            var oldUrl = form.action;

                            if (url) {
                               form.action = url;
                            }
                            var e = null;
                            try {
                                this.form.submit();
                            } catch (e) {
                            }
                            this.form.action = oldUrl;
                            if (e) {
                                throw e;
                            }

                            if (button && button != 'undefined') {
                                button.disabled = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }.bind(productAddToCartForm);

                    productAddToCartForm.submitLight = function(button, url){
                        if(this.validator) {
                            var nv = Validation.methods;
                            delete Validation.methods['required-entry'];
                            delete Validation.methods['validate-one-required'];
                            delete Validation.methods['validate-one-required-by-name'];
                            // Remove custom datetime validators
                            for (var methodName in Validation.methods) {
                                if (methodName.match(/^validate-datetime-.*/i)) {
                                    delete Validation.methods[methodName];
                                }
                            }

                            if (this.validator.validate()) {
                                if (url) {
                                    this.form.action = url;
                                }
                                this.form.submit();
                            }
                            Object.extend(Validation.methods, nv);
                        }
                    }.bind(productAddToCartForm);
                //]]>
                </script>
            </div>

            <div class="product-collateral toggle-content tabs">
                <?php if ($detailedInfoGroup = $this->getChildGroup('detailed_info', 'getChildHtml')):?>
                    <dl id="collateral-tabs" class="collateral-tabs">
                        <?php foreach ($detailedInfoGroup as $alias => $html):?>
                            <dt class="tab"><span><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getChildData($alias, 'title')) ?></span></dt>
                            <dd class="tab-container">
                                <div class="tab-content"><?php echo $html ?></div>
                            </dd>
                        <?php endforeach;?>
                    </dl>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>

            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('upsell_products') ?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_additional_data') ?>

        </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not fulfill your requirement easily

There have ***few conditions***  for ***showing the category images at product view***

If ***current product url*** is contain ***category path***.Then from **registry variable**  `Mage::registry('current_category')`.You can get `category object` easily.Then  you get `category banner`

```
<?php
if(Mage::registry('current_category')):
$_category=Mage::registry('current_category');
$_helper    = Mage::helper('catalog/output');
    $_imgHtml   = '';
    if ($_imgUrl = $_category->getImageUrl()) {
        $_imgHtml = '<p class="category-image"><img src="'.$_imgUrl.'"     alt="'.$this->escapeHtml($_category->getName()).'" title="'.$this->escapeHtml($_category->getName()).'" /></p>';
        $_imgHtml = $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_imgHtml, 'image');
    }?>

    <?php if($_imgUrl): ?>
    <?php echo $_imgHtml ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

If `this registry variable does not give result` then you need to get  `category id's` from product `(getCategory())`.

Then using ***category model***,you can get ***that particulate product categories banner images***.

```
<?php
$ids = $_product->getCategoryIds();
if(!empty($ids)){
    foreach($ids as $eachCatid):
    $_category= Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())->load(eachCatid);
$_helper    = Mage::helper('catalog/output');
    $_imgHtml   = '';
    if ($_imgUrl = $_category->getImageUrl()) {
        $_imgHtml = '<p class="category-image"><img src="'.$_imgUrl.'"     alt="'.$this->escapeHtml($_category->getName()).'" title="'.$this->escapeHtml($_category->getName()).'" /></p>';
        $_imgHtml = $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_imgHtml, 'image');
    }?>

    <?php if($_imgUrl): ?>
    <?php echo $_imgHtml ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php
    endforeach;
 } ?>
```

Add `<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>`code at top of ***product/view.phtml***

Comment: can you please tell.the object name of product in view .phtml'

Comment: Where would I get the object name please?

Comment: can u plz show view.phtml code?

Comment: Added view.phtml code to orgiinal post Amit thanks.

Comment: want to see product/view.phtml  full code..

Comment: Updated Amit...

Comment: hey have you check my answer...?

Comment: Hello Amity,  I will check today with your additional code the 'get product' and update you.